# How to place same canvas on multiple cameras in Unity?

Tags: unity, camera, ui-design

I know how to do It on one, but I don't know how to do it using multiple cameras, 3 of them are important, i want to show the whole UI except for the minimap. I need to change the camera angle on some spots, while keeping the same canvas for displaying the number of coins XP and the current level.

Comment: Set the cameras as the main-camera when changing into them, through script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Option 1:

Set the canvas to be a `Screen Space - Overlay`

This mode means that the canvas renders *last* directly to the screen (in screen space), regardless of which cameras are active and how they're displaying what they display.

## Option 2:

Set the canvas to be a `Screen Space - Camera` and change which camera it renders on when appropriate.

This mode means that the canvas is the *last thing rendered by the indicated camera* and will only render on that camera's view (and if another camera renders afterwards, it will render *over* the canvas). By changing which camera is active you also change which camera the canvas renders to, you maintain the visibility of the canvas.

Option 1 is likely the preferred solution, but depending on your exact needs and camera setup, Option 2 might be what you're looking for.

Comment: Not actually how SSC works, at least not in current version Unity. It actually puts the canvas on a plane in front of the camera, which can in case environment clipping. It is possible to configure to only exist epsilon away from the ncp, but artifacts can persist; especially with very fast-moving or erratic cameras.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution: duplicate another canvas then set this canvas to new camera.
You could use this simple script to read the raw_image texture from the target canvas:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;


public class CameraTexture : MonoBehaviour
{
    public RawImage camera_texture;
    private RawImage rawImage;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rawImage = GetComponent<RawImage>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        rawImage.texture = camera_texture.texture;
    }
}
```